# Docker: Permanently sourcing file when building an image

Tags: docker

I am following [these](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/nginx/enterprise/install_language_runtime.html) instructions to build a `docker` image from `python3.7` that also contains `ruby` - i need `2.1.5` specifically (don't ask).

So my `Dockerfile` is this:

```
FROM python:3.7

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    dirmngr \
    gnupg2 \
    && curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import - \
    && gpg2 --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB \
    && curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io |  bash -s stable \
    && usermod -a -G rvm root \
    && source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh \
    && rvm install ruby-2.1.5
```

The build completes with success but the end image does not have `ruby` in its path which is the result of this command `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` actually not having any effect during the build.

As soon as I get a cmd in the container and running it, `ruby` is available.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results.

So, all `RUN` in `Dockerfile` will just affect the image build, not container. You should put any `source` in `entrypoint` or `cmd`. Or make symbol link in Dockerfile to link it to `/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you source a script inside a shell that only exists for the command, it will not have any lasting effect on any future commands.

Try this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh; command1; command2; command3;"
```